# Can I use the same .pem file for both Development and Distribution Profile

Tags: iphone, objective-c, certificate

While making my application to be listened for Push Notification, I have read the guideline given by Apple. It is clearly mentioned that Certificate for Sandbox and Production should be separately created.
My question is, is that Production certificate goes with **"Distribution Profile"** also?
If yes, then does this means that even though I am creating this profile for testing purpose I have to attach my **Production Certificate** with that Profile?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The debug/developer pem has to be used with a developer mobileprovision and Apple's sandbox APNS URL
2. The distribution pem can be used with an Adhoc and App Store mobileprovision and Apple's production APNS URL

Not sure if this answers your question. If you need any more details, please specify in your question.

Comment: For adhoc, I am creating a separate provisioning profile. My question is, is it required for me to create a new SSL Certificate and attach it to this profile or my existing certificate (already attached with the profile used for development) may attach with that adhoc provisioning profile?

Comment: You should use a production pem with an adhoc profile, so yes, you will need to create a Distribution pem for use with the adhoc mobileprovision.

Comment: For further information, refer to the Mac OS X Note (and the next paragraph) in the section "Provisioning and Development" in this document - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ProvisioningDevelopment/ProvisioningDevelopment.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW1

Comment: However, in my case for Adhoc also, developer PEM is workable and not distribution PEM.